# Site announcement banners shouldn't be shown in Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I was surprised to see the Code of Conduct banner when viewing questions within a Team. It felt out of place, given the [general messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) that Teams is a 'private, secure home for your team’s questions and answers'.

Hot Network Questions and the yellow Blog/Featured/Hot-Meta-Posts box are already hidden, giving a (good) feeling of my Team being separated from the network at large. It feels like this should be extended to general announcements.

The announcement is not relevant in this case, and future messages might be undesirable to show to paying, corporate customers for a litany of other reasons.

Comment: Just realized that the code of conduct [page is present on Teams as well](https://stackoverflow.com/c/sobotics/conduct) but half of it doesn't make sense as there's no option to flag.

Comment: Also, Teams customers probably already have a corporate code of conduct, and their own IRL penalties for not following it (like firing).